# Child element doesn't take the focus of the parent in safari browsers

Tags: ios, css, macos, safari, sass

I have a container that when I click it gets focus and show the hidden content inside of him.

Now, in the hidden container there is a button when you click on it gets the focus and closes the parent.

It works in all browser except safari on ios and macos.

I'm looking for a clean CSS Solution.

HTML

```
<div class="box" tabindex="0">
  <div class="front">CLICK ME</div>
  <div class="hidden">
    <button class="close">close button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

SASS

```
.box{
  position:relative;
  height:200px; width:200px;
}

.front,
.hidden{height:100%; width:100%; position:absolute; }

.close{height:100px; width:100px;}

.box:focus{
  .front{display:none;}
  .hidden{display:block;}
}

.front{background:blue; color:white;}
.hidden{background:red; display:none;}
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/OjrLwN)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the button tag into a different element (e.g. DIV) with a tabindex attribute and then it works in Safari as well.

Safari, and apparently some other browsers on iOS have strange focus behaviour for buttons. It seems they never get focus, even with tabindex.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button#Clicking_and_focus

Example

```
<button class="close">close button</button><!-- not working -->
<!-- Use instead -->
<div class="close" tabindex="0" role="button"></div><!-- working -->
```

[DEMO](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rzoOzb)

Answer (score -2):

Solution for iOS will be holding Option Key + Tab key. Then button will be tabbed on.